# A Cross-Platform Localization Resource Format

Tags: c++, file, localization, internationalization, format

I want to keep my replacement strings (German, French, etc) in a file format that is standard-ish and useable across Windows and Linux platforms.  Thus VC++ resource files are ruled out right away.

What file format do others prefer to use for keeping these l10n resources?  Two more features I'd like the format to support are:

1. the "key" for indexing l10n strings is itself an English string, rather than an enum.
2. the format can carry a message digest, so I could verify there has been no tampering.

My intent would be to use a function (e.g. `wstring foo = GetString(L"I am %1% years old");`) that feeds the boost::format or boost::wformat functions.  Notice that the key fed to GetString is a string, not an enum.

Obviously I can use whatever XML format (or otherwise) I'd like to dream up.  But I'd rather use something that is somewhat standard.

Comment: This is probably a business-decision, but just in case you haven't though about it.  I wouldn't enforce non-tampering with translation files.  You might get a motivated user to translate your application in a language you don't offer support for.  This can potentially increase you user base for free!  You just need to add a support page where you provide links to "unofficial" translations and where users can post their own.  You'd be surprised how many you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a standard format, use [gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_gettext) and msgfmt to make binary .mo files.  The format comes from Unix, but is usable cross platform.  Audacity, which is Linux/Mac/Windows, uses it.

1) The key ***is*** the English string.
2) The standard format doesn't come with an anti-tamper approach, so you will need to cook up your own.

There is also an editor, poEdit, and an emacs mode for working with the translations in the intermediate textual .po format.

Comment: I know this is available for windows as other projects, including Django, use it.  You might want to search for pre-compiled binairies.  Some of these UNIX libraries require lots of expertise to compile under windows!

Answer (score 0):

We used a library called I18N (I'm sure there are a ton of implementations named the same way all over).  The keys and translations were stored in a .txt file, and used some hash for faster lookups.  We modified it some to improve the context - it used a context of filename, so you could not use multiple translations of the same string literal in the same file.

Usage was something like Translated = String::Format(I18N("I am %d years old"), years);

We would periodically run a separately executable against our sourcecode to parse out all the various I18N entries, rehash them, and update the file with any new additions.

Unfortunately I can't find any attributes to the author in the source.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is one, but if there is chances are it is mentioned somewhere at lisa.org: http://www.lisa.org/Standards.30.0.html