# How to translate a C++ program with ICU?

Tags: c++, icu

How can I use ICU to translate my program, I'm using c++, I can't find any example. Can it be done directly with ICU? I saw that it names other tools like gettext, but I'm already using ICU in my project to deal with string and the fewer libraries I have to use the better.

I have read https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/locale/localizing.html but it does not say how.

Comment: Translating your program is a long process. (1) Extract all literal strings into a string resource and tokenize the replaceable elements. (2) Get the strings translated into the language(s) you want to support.  (3) Go round-the-bend trying to deal with (a) left-to-right vs right-to-left; (b) currency and date localisation.  ICU is a Unicode processing API, it does not do translation(s).

Comment: I thought so until I found this https://lokalise.com/blog/complete-guide-to-icu-message-format/  and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494396/icu-vs-boost-locale-in-c, where it appears how to use ICU but for javascript.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264969/a-cross-platform-localization-resource-format